# Databricks: Dataframe groupby agg, collector set include duplicate values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, databricks

Suppose I am having a dataset df like in the following

```
col1   col2 
1      A
1      B
1      C
2      B
2      B
2      C
```

I want to the dataset with col1 and make col2 as an array using the following code

```
var df2=df.groupBy("col1").agg(collect_set("col2").alias("col2"))
```

then df2 will be

```
COl1    Col2
1       A,B,C
2       B,C
```

How to change the code so that I can have

```
COl1    Col2
1       A,B,C
2       B,B,C
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `collect_list` instead of `collect_set` because collect_set returns `a set of objects with duplicate elements eliminate`:

```
scala> var df2=df.groupBy("col1").agg(collect_list("col2").alias("col2"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: array<string>]
scala> df2.show
+----+---------+
|col1|     col2|
+----+---------+
|   1|[a, b, c]|
|   2|[b, b, c]|
+----+---------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelChau: It's my pleasure. Please accept the answer and upvote it.